# How to find the table name from the pg_subscription_rel.srrelid (postgres logical replication)

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have postgresql logical replication setup between two servers and it seems to be working for the most part, except for one row when running `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_subscription;` never changes from `srsubstate = d`.

Is it possible to find the table that this row is referring to using the `srrelid`?

Or any other way to debug why this is the case?

---

```
my_db=# SELECT * FROM pg_subscription_rel;
 srsubid | srrelid | srsubstate |   srsublsn   
---------+---------+------------+--------------
  209358 |  208195 | r          | D83/BED60B88
<< clipped data >>
  209358 |  208164 | r          | D83/BEC66E90
  209358 |  207290 | d          | 
  209358 |  208436 | r          | D83/BED60AA8
<< clipped data >>
  209358 |  208328 | r          | D83/BED57BF8
(74 rows)
```

```
my_db=# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_subscription;
 subid  |  subname  |  pid  | relid | received_lsn |      last_msg_send_time      |     last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |       latest_end_time        
--------+-----------+-------+-------+--------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+------------------------------
 209358 | s_upgrade | 26880 |       | DA9/C31E5560 | 2020-11-16 16:53:35.66203+11 | 2020-11-16 16:53:35.669512+11 | DA9/C31E5560   | 2020-11-16 16:53:35.66203+11
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join it to `pg_class`

```
SELECT s.subname AS subscription_name,
       c.relnamespace::regnamespace::text as table_schema,
       c.relname as table_name,
       rel.srsublsn,
       case rel.srsubstate 
         when 'i' then 'initialized'
         when 'd' then 'copying'
         when 's' then 'synchronized'
         when 'r' then 'ready'
       end as state
FROM pg_catalog.pg_subscription s
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel rel ON rel.srsubid = s.oid
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c on c.oid = rel.srrelid
```